# CLion на Mac Os

Tags: macos, mac, clion

Добрый день!
Установил Clion на Macbook не могу найти компилятор, чтоб его прописать для (Си, С++). 
Вопрос где находится компилятор на Mac. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, последовательность следующая:
Устанавливаем Xcode => Clion (подтянет компилятор из Xcode)